# layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind not called

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am writing a custom flow layout for a UICollectionView.
I can see and scroll the cells.

The problem is that I can't make the supplementary view for the section header appear.

So,

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)
      layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind 
      atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

never gets called.

In the data source this method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)
      collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
      viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind 
      atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

also **never gets called**.

How can I make it so those methods are called?

EDIT:
This is the layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSMutableArray * attributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.layoutInfo allKeys] count]];
    for(NSIndexPath * indexPath in self.layoutInfo) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes = [self.layoutInfo objectForKey:indexPath];
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, itemAttributes.frame)) {
            [attributes addObject:itemAttributes];
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

So even with this the two methods for the supplementary view are not called.

Answer (score 11):

You need to implement [`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012185-CH1-SW9) to return an attributes instance for each supplementary view (in addition to each cell):

> Subclasses must override this method and use it to return layout information for all items whose view intersects the specified rectangle. Your implementation should return attributes for all visual elements, including cells, supplementary views, and decoration views.

Comment: so then I need to detect the indexPath.row == 0 if I only have one section and if so that is the frame of the supplementary view I need calculate and return?

Comment: @zumzum section indexPaths and items/cells indexPaths are separate collections. You will have a section header with (0, 0) and an item/cell with (0, 0) too.